# How to setup scp with custom parameters?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, centos-7, scp

I want to setup a centos server from where users can copy files using their user id, password and a `key`. Based on the unique key I want to give the user access to multiple files. Have figured out a way to setup the user authentication part with `MySQL`.

So the command should look something like this:

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt someKey
```

But cannot figure out how to serve multiple files based on a `somekey`/ `String`.

Is there a way to setup this?

Comment: So, you want to copy multiple files? i.e. replace `foobar.txt` with `foo* bar* *.txt` ??

Comment: No, based on the key they provide, they will be able to download files. For eg: they type `scp user@hostname abcd_1234` they will be able to download `x.txt, y.txt and z.txt.` These files are based on the key.

Comment: Seems like a weird way. If we knew more about how/when the files and keys are generated a suggestion migt present itself. As it i is now I'm wondering why not copy/symlink the files users have access to their home directory?

Comment: @Nifle The key is generated when the user selects some data on my website. Now that data should be made available to the user when they `scp` using that key.

Answer (score 2):

A way to implement that would be to use home folders and symlinks.

1. Create a directory containing all the files. 
   For instance, `/var/pub/repo_files`.
2. Order your files by roles, within separate directories. 
   For instance,
   `/var/pub/repo_files/files_for_group_1/`,
   `/var/pub/repo_files/files_for_group_2/`, `/var/pub/repo_files/files_for_group_3/`, ...
3. Create a system user for each user allowed to `scp`,
   add ssh public key as you would do for a simple ssh access. 
   Double check they have a home directory `/home/userA/`.
4. Create symbolic links from repository folders to users' home directories:
   `ln -s /var/pub/repo_files/files_for_group_1/ /home/userA/files_for_group_1`. 
   Repeat for other folders he's allowed to download.
5. Fine tune files' permissions by assigning users to system groups
   (`useradd -G group1 userA`). 
   It would be great to make it read-only, for instance.

You could distribute personal credentials (user id, key and pass) to everyone or create  a generic one for each set of files reflecting each permission combinations.

Comment: But how do I do this dynamically? Like those files need to be served up based on the key provided by the user.